# How to find source of scala.MatchError?

Tags: string, scala, debugging

I have a parser program in Scala sending `string` to it and breaking the string and parse. I am getting the following error on that which I don't even know which part of the program is wrong:

```
 Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: xxxx/xml/test3D.xml (of class java.lang.String)
```

What are the possibilities that I need to check and what is the best way to solve these kind of errors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is exact place where exception occurred and it is described by file name and line number in this file. For example, look at this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: 7 (of class java.lang.Integer)
at stackoverflow.M$.delayedEndpoint$stackoverflow$M$1(Functions.scala:35)
at stackoverflow.M$delayedInit$body.apply(Functions.scala:30)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
```

Here you can see that exception  cause is on line **35** in **Functions.scala** file. The second line in a stack trace is the line where exception was thrown. Check this line!

MatchError occurs whenever an object doesn't match any pattern of a pattern matching expression.